# Finding out if processbuilder generated process threw exception or finished cleanly

Tags: java, out-of-memory, processbuilder

I am developing a program in Java that uses processbuilder to start another java program, so far I have no problems getting the other program to run, however I need to find out if the other program exited cleanly or threw an exception (Specifically I am looking for a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError). Putting the process.start() itself in a Try Catch block does not work, as I am never entering the catch block, even in cases when I am sure the child process threw an exception. Is there any way to check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Process you start will return an exit code. You can get it by calling

```
process.exitValue()
```

In the Java program you run you need to do System.exit(int_here) to indicate what happened. 0 means no error normally, but you're free to not follow any standards and make your own exit codes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as an Exception when you start a external process. You can only get the [exit-code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29) (which should be non-zero if there was a abnormal termination) or read the standard output and (especially) standard error streams.

Comment: Thanks, wish I could mark both answers accepted, this is also the right answer, I just marked the other one because of the specific instructions for getting the exit code.